# Image not saving in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am downloading a file using the following:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL HERE"]];
```

Displaying it with the following:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

And saving it to the device with the following:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pth = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.localFile];    

NSData *d1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,1.0f)];
[d1 writeToFile:pth atomically:YES];
```

Photo displays fine in my UIImageView. But when I reload the application and display the file, I get the following error:

```
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/422122E1-3244-46CE-BB6C-123C750E2191/Documents/14741078_1.jpg'
         error = 2 (No such file or directory)
ImageIO: <ERROR> JPEGNot a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what `NSDataReadingMapped` does. That's only useful if you're reading from the filesystem.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - I removed that, thank you. Was not related to the issue though as I was still getting data that I am populating a UIImage with. Thanks again.

Comment: once check the path contains image or not if not change the path that is only the problem after seeing your code..

Comment: Can you add the code you use to read the saved image when you reload the application?

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have just resolved the same issue.

Don't change your load method.
But save your image like this :

```
NSError* error = nil;
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0f) writeToFile:pth options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```